# TListbox - Manipulating the layout of Images and Text?

Tags: delphi, tlistbox

I have been having a play around with the TListBox control, and drawing images and changing the font styles etc. I want to step it up a little, and try manipulating the items some more with indentation and multi level indenting.

Take a look at this image for a better idea:

[image]

The idea is that items in the list that are positioned between start and end items should be indented accordingly.

So, to give an idea I edited the screenshot in Paint, so it would look something like this:

[image]

What would be the way to approach this? My thought was to iterate through the listbox and return in 2 separate variable the amount of start and end items, then somehow determine where the other items are and if the fit between - but my logic is never so good :(

For ease of use, I have provided below the code to show how I am drawing the images and styles:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ImgList, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    ListBox2: TListBox;
    TabSheet3: TTabSheet;
    ListBox3: TListBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBox1MeasureItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      var Height: Integer);
    procedure ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure ListBox2MeasureItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      var Height: Integer);
    procedure ListBox2DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure ListBox3MeasureItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      var Height: Integer);
    procedure ListBox3DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

// assign quick identifiers to image indexes
const
  imgLayout      = 0;
  imgCalculator  = 1;
  imgComment     = 2;
  imgTime        = 3;
  imgStart       = 4;
  imgEnd         = 5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ListStyle: TListBoxStyle;
begin
  // set the listbox style here
  ListStyle := lbOwnerDrawVariable;
  ListBox1.Style := ListStyle;
  ListBox2.Style := ListStyle;
  ListBox3.Style := ListStyle;
end;

{******************************************************************************}

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  TextPosition: Integer;
  Images: TImageList;
begin
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  Images := ImageList1;

  // draw the images
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Layout' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgLayout);
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Calculator' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top,
      imgCalculator);
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Comment' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgComment);
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Time' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgTime);
  end;

  // positions the text
  TextPosition := (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextHeight
    (Text)) div 2;

  // displays the text
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + Images.Width + 8,
    Rect.Top + TextPosition, TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[index]);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1MeasureItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  var Height: Integer);
begin
  Height := ImageList1.Height;
end;

{******************************************************************************}

procedure TForm1.ListBox2DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  TextPosition: Integer;
  Images: TImageList;
begin
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  Images := ImageList1;

  // draw the images
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Layout' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgLayout);
    TListBox(Control).Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Calculator' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top,
      imgCalculator);
    TListBox(Control).Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
    TListBox(Control).Canvas.Font.Style := [fsItalic];
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Comment' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgComment);
    TListBox(Control).Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Time' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgTime);
  end;

  // positions the text
  TextPosition := (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextHeight
    (Text)) div 2;

  // displays the text
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + Images.Width + 8,
    Rect.Top + TextPosition, TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[index]);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox2MeasureItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  var Height: Integer);
begin
  Height := ImageList1.Height;
end;

{******************************************************************************}

procedure TForm1.ListBox3DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  TextPosition: Integer;
  Images: TImageList;
begin
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  Images := ImageList1;

  // draw the images
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Layout' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgLayout);
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Calculator' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top,
      imgCalculator);
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Comment' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgComment);
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Time' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgTime);
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Start' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top,
      imgStart);
    TListBox(Control).Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  end else
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'End' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgEnd);
    TListBox(Control).Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  end;

  // positions the text
  TextPosition := (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextHeight
    (Text)) div 2;

  // displays the text
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + Images.Width + 8,
    Rect.Top + TextPosition, TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[index]);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox3MeasureItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  var Height: Integer);
begin
  Height := ImageList1.Height;
end;

{******************************************************************************}

end.
```

I would appreciate some tips on how I could determine manipulating the items. I know I can change where the bitmap and texts are placed, but it is identifying if an item falls between the groups or not, and if it does set the correct indent level.

I hope this makes sense thats why I put some mock pictures up.

Thanks :)

PS, I never write small posts sorry!

**UPDATE WITH WORKING DEMO**

I have accepted Sertac's answer which I have working perfectly thanks Sertac.

To help others who may be viewing - and because I have been learning OOP I want to show my code to see if it is any good :)

I have made 2 units, Lib.pas contains the classes for the list items, and Unit1.pas is the Form1 unit (I shortened unit 1 to make it clearer to see what is going on):

**Lib.pas**

```
unit Lib;

interface

uses
  Classes, StdCtrls;

type
  TMyListData = class(TObject)
  public
    fCaption: string;
    fImageIndex: integer;
  public
    property Caption: string read fCaption write fCaption;
    property ImageIndex: integer read fImageIndex write fImageIndex;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

type
  TLayoutItem     = class(TMyListData);
  TCalculatorItem = class(TMyListData);
  TCommentItem    = class(TMyListData);
  TTimeItem       = class(TMyListData);
  TStartItem      = class(TMyListData);
  TEndItem        = class(TMyListData);

const
  imgLayout       = 0;
  imgCalculator   = 1;
  imgComment      = 2;
  imgTime         = 3;
  imgStart        = 4;
  imgEnd          = 5;

procedure NewLayoutItem(aListBox: TListBox);
procedure NewCalculatorItem(aListBox: TListBox);
procedure NewCommentItem(aListBox: TListBox);
procedure NewTimeItem(aListBox: TListBox);
procedure NewStartItem(aListBox: TListBox);
procedure NewEndItem(aListBox: TListBox);
procedure DeleteItem(aListBox: TListBox; aIndex: integer);
procedure CalculateIndents(aListBox: TListBox);

implementation

{ TMyListData }

constructor TMyListData.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
end;

destructor TMyListData.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure NewLayoutItem(aListBox: TListBox);
var
  Obj: TLayoutItem;
begin
  Obj := TLayoutItem.Create;
  try
    Obj.Caption := 'Layout';
    Obj.ImageIndex := imgLayout;

    aListBox.AddItem(Obj.Caption, Obj);
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;

  CalculateIndents(aListBox);
end;

procedure NewCalculatorItem(aListBox: TListBox);
var
  Obj: TCalculatorItem;
begin
  Obj := TCalculatorItem.Create;
  try
    Obj.Caption := 'Calculator';
    Obj.ImageIndex := imgCalculator;

    aListBox.AddItem(Obj.Caption, Obj);
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;

  CalculateIndents(aListBox);
end;

procedure NewCommentItem(aListBox: TListBox);
var
  Obj: TCommentItem;
begin
  Obj := TCommentItem.Create;
  try
    Obj.Caption := 'Comment';
    Obj.ImageIndex := imgComment;

    aListBox.AddItem(Obj.Caption, Obj);
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;

  CalculateIndents(aListBox);
end;

procedure NewTimeItem(aListBox: TListBox);
var
  Obj: TTimeItem;
begin
  Obj := TTimeItem.Create;
  try
    Obj.Caption := 'Time';
    Obj.ImageIndex := imgTime;

    aListBox.AddItem(Obj.Caption, Obj);
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;

  CalculateIndents(aListBox);
end;

procedure NewStartItem(aListBox: TListBox);
var
  Obj: TStartItem;
begin
  Obj := TStartItem.Create;
  try
    Obj.Caption := 'Start';
    Obj.ImageIndex := imgStart;

    aListBox.AddItem(Obj.Caption, Obj);
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;

  CalculateIndents(aListBox);
end;

procedure NewEndItem(aListBox: TListBox);
var
  Obj: TEndItem;
begin
  Obj := TEndItem.Create;
  try
    Obj.Caption := 'End';
    Obj.ImageIndex := imgEnd;

    aListBox.AddItem(Obj.Caption, Obj);
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;

  CalculateIndents(aListBox);
end;


procedure DeleteItem(aListBox: TListBox; aIndex: integer);
begin
  aListBox.Items.Delete(aIndex);
  aListBox.Items.Objects[aIndex] := nil;

  CalculateIndents(aListBox);
end;

procedure CalculateIndents(aListBox: TListBox);
var
  i: Integer;
  Indent: Integer;
begin
  Indent := 0;

  for i := 0 to aListBox.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if aListBox.Items[i] = 'End' then
      Dec(Indent);

    if Indent > -1 then
      aListBox.Items.Objects[i] := Pointer(Indent);

    if aListBox.Items[i] = 'Start' then
      Inc(Indent);
  end;

  for i := aListBox.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if (aListBox.Items[i] = 'End') and (Indent = -1) then
    begin
      DeleteItem(aListBox, i);
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ImgList, ComCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    lbMain: TListBox;
    btnLayout: TBitBtn;
    btnCalculator: TBitBtn;
    btnComment: TBitBtn;
    btnTime: TBitBtn;
    btnStartGroup: TBitBtn;
    btnEndGroup: TBitBtn;
    btnDelete: TBitBtn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure lbMainMeasureItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      var Height: Integer);
    procedure lbMainDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure btnLayoutClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCalculatorClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCommentClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnTimeClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStartGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnEndGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Lib;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // set the listbox style here
  lbMain.Style := lbOwnerDrawVariable;
end;

procedure TForm1.lbMainDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  TextPosition: Integer;
  Images: TImageList;
begin
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  Images := ImageList1;

  // draw the images
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Layout' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4 +
                8 * Integer(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
                Rect.Top, imgLayout);
  end
  else if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Calculator' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4 +
                8 * Integer(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
                Rect.Top, imgCalculator);
  end
  else if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Comment' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4 +
                8 * Integer(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
                Rect.Top, imgComment);
  end
  else if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Time' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4 +
                8 * Integer(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
                Rect.Top, imgTime);
  end
  else if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Start' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4 +
                8 * Integer(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
                Rect.Top, imgStart);
  end
  else if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'End' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4 +
                8 * Integer(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
                Rect.Top, imgEnd);
  end;

  // positions the text
  TextPosition := (Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextHeight
    (Text)) div 2;

  // displays the text
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextOut(
    Rect.Left + Images.Width + 8 + 8 * Longint(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
    Rect.Top + TextPosition, TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[index]);
end;

procedure TForm1.lbMainMeasureItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  var Height: Integer);
begin
  Height := ImageList1.Height;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnLayoutClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewLayoutItem(lbMain);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCalculatorClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewCalculatorItem(lbMain);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCommentClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewCommentItem(lbMain);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTimeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewTimeItem(lbMain);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStartGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewStartItem(lbMain);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnEndGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewEndItem(lbMain);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if lbMain.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    DeleteItem(lbMain, lbMain.ItemIndex);
  end;
end;

end.
```

[image]

It can be made better, ie assigning the image indexes based on the Items.Objects[] property but this works perfectly :)

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why are you trying to do this with TListBox. This seems like a perfect place to be using a TTreeView instead; it has built-in support for the indentation, images based on content type, and so forth. It seems like you're doing a lot of extra work for no reason. (I thought at first you must be using FireMonkey, but a review of the code doesn't indicate that you are.)

Comment: If you want an entirely custom look-and-feel list, you can also use TScrollBox and design your elements on TFrames. Set up a simple Managed Array to handle items in the same way as TListBox.Items (easily done), and then there are literally no limits on what you can create.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't have Delphi XE2 unfortunately, also I am fully aware of the Treeview which would provide a better way of displaying the data as you say. On the other hand however, for a simple listbox display I thought this would be a good thing to try and do. I was just experimenting with the TListbox, and having read some more on Fire monkey after your comment I see that Treeview cannot be used as it is a Windows control, so doing this with a listbox has its advantages in that respect.

Comment: Craig, no. This code will not help you eventually with FireMonkey - FM's ListBox is in no way compatible with the VCL one. And the VCL's TListBox is a wrapper around the underlying Windows common control, and isn't designed to be used the way you're trying to use it (which is why you're finding it difficult). Looks like @Sertac did a good job with an answer, though (as usual).

Comment: But it also all depends on having a good idea of how it is going to work before re-building it. It's a technique called "making a prototype".

Comment: @Ken I don't know too much about Firemonkey, and I only use Delphi as a hobby. I had no interest in fire monkey really, but if a fire monkey listbox could do the same as above I thought it could have some benefits, but I see now that is not the case. Oh well, sertac did a great job anyway, and I can see some uses for it in standard VCL applications :)

Comment: @JerryDodge, was your comment addressed to anyone in particular? I can't see anything it's pertinent to in the other comments...

Comment: I'm looking forward to using Firemonkey, it's for HD apps. There is no way however to 'convert' any delphi app to firemonkey, that's next to impossible.

Comment: @JerryDodge, thanks for the definition of what a `prototype` is, then. However, coding an entire app for one API that has no direct correlation to a different one isn't a `prototype`. A prototype refers to appearances, not anything to do with the underlying code. And I still don't see any pertinence to the comment, especially since your application of `prototype` is misplaced. :)

Comment: @JerryDodge, of course not. But they should at least have something to do with the post you're commenting on (or at least other comments to that post). How about I post a comment "More dogs like Alpo." to some random programming question that has nothing to do with dogs - is that a valid comment? :) Regardless, I think this has gone far enough; we're just making noise now.

Comment: Agreed. Deleting irrelevant comments above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to iterate over items and modify the text to indicate indentation:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Indent: Integer;
begin

  ...

  Indent := 0;
  for i := 0 to ListBox3.Items.Count - 1 do begin
    if Pos('End', ListBox3.Items[i]) > 0 then
      Dec(Indent);
    if Indent > 0 then
      ListBox3.Items[i] := StringOfChar(#32, 2 * Indent) + ListBox3.Items[i];
    if Pos('Start', ListBox3.Items[i]) > 0 then
      Inc(Indent);
  end;
end;
```

Since items' text are changed, this approach requires to test the text accordingly when drawing:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox3DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  TextPosition: Integer;
  Images: TImageList;
begin
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  Images := ImageList1;

  // draw the images
  if Pos('Layout', TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index]) > 0 then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top, imgLayout);
  end else
  if Pos('Calculator', TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index]) > 0 then
    ..
```

(With this approach, indenting images would be a little work, count the leading spaces in item text, and so on..)

If items' objects are not used already, a slightly better approach can be to store indentation as an integer, and use that information when drawing. E.g. when iterating:

```
Indent := 0;
for i := 0 to ListBox3.Items.Count - 1 do begin
  if ListBox3.Items[i] = 'Start' then
    Inc(Indent);
  ListBox3.Items.Objects[i] := Pointer(Indent);
  if ListBox3.Items[i] = 'End' then
    Dec(Indent);
end;
```

When drawing:

```
  ..
  if TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[Index] = 'Layout' then
  begin
    Images.Draw(TListBox(Control).Canvas, Rect.Left + 4 +
                8 * Integer(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
                Rect.Top, imgLayout);

  ..
  // displays the text
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextOut(
    Rect.Left + Images.Width + 8 + 8 * Longint(TListBox(Control).Items.Objects[Index]),
    Rect.Top + TextPosition, TListBox(Control).Items.Strings[index]);
  ..
```

Comment: +1, I have not looked at all the code yet, but storing the indent value as a pointer to each item is a good idea for new items. Let me look over the rest of the code thanks Sertac...

Comment: @Craig - > *"new items"* > Adding is fine, but when inserting, iterating the items after the insert position would be required.

Comment: I am writing a demo based on the information you have provided (as I am learning OOP I can see what you experts think of my objects code :) stay tuned..

Comment: I accepted your answer, and posted my demo based on your information, I hope this looks good thanks :)

Comment: @Craig - If you've used similar code as in the question, you may receive some little objections :). Such as, there's no point in using `ListStyle` variable in 'FormCreate'. Or, there's no point in attaching different handlers of different controls having the exact same code. I.e. you can attach `ListBox2.OnMeasureItem` to the same handler of 'ListBox1' in OI. ;)

Comment: I know you can assign to each handler in the object inspector, I just posted it so you can see the styles set at runtime :)

Comment: @Craig - I have an error that leads to indent 'End' 1 indentation left then intended. Will modify the answer.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, I also lined up the End correctly with the Start, I will update that portion..

Comment: @Craig - Sorry to bother you again :), but my actual error was in iterating the items, the order of statements should be "test start", "assign indentation", "test end". Of course your fix works too, but the other way around wouldn't require to treat "end" differently while drawing.

Comment: Feel free to edit my original post if you need to, your solution would be better ;)

Comment: @Craig - No, no.. it's fine, just a different view :)

Comment: Ok, well thank you very much for your help it was most helpful ;)

Comment: I have updated the code in my first post one final time, it handles the end block, it will not try to add an end block if it is at the first indent. The CalculateIndents procedure can be modified in so many different ways though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should probably use the TTreeView instead, which already supports indenting child items.

To answer your question, I think you could use recursion to draw the items in your TListBox. Using recursion, it is easy to see how many levels deep you are.

This is how most parsers work, such as HTML parsers.

Here's some pseudo code that illustrates the concept:

```
procedure DrawBranch(branch: TMyList; indent: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Draw the current branch, using the indent value
  branch.Draw;
  // Iterate through all of the child branches
  for i := 0 to branch.Children.Count - 1 do
  begin
    // Each time we recurse further, we add 1 to the indent 
    DrawBranch(branch.Child[i], indent + 1);
  end;
end;

procedure DrawTree;
begin
  // Start the whole thing off with the root branch
  // We start the indent at 0
  DrawBranch(root, 0);
end;
```

You'll want a "hidden" root node in your case.

You'd use similar same logic to add your items to a TTreeView.